# Golang Gorm db.raw with CloudSQL for Update SQL query not working?

Tags: go, google-cloud-sql, go-gorm

I have this SQL query, which in isolation works fine with 2 rows affected absolutely fine

```
update chores set life_status ='Processing' where life_status = 'Active' and chore_type ='Shared' and money_assigned > 0
```

But when I try gorm's execution variant statements in golang i.e.

```
err := h.db.Raw("update chores set life_status ='Processing' where life_status = 'Active' and chore_type ='Shared' and money_assigned > ? ", 0).Error
```

OR

```
numRecsToProcess := h.db.Raw("update chores set life_status ='Processing' where life_status = 'Active' and chore_type ='Shared' and money_assigned > ? ", 0).RowsAffected
```

None of these update statements are affecting any change in underlying DB. Is there something I am missing from Gorm usage functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `h.db.Exec` instead of `h.db.Raw`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked ... Maybe Raw SQL execution has such limitation in go-gorm

Comment: I had a brief look at the code, Raw() does not immediately execute anything. You have to call other methods on the returned handle.

Comment: Since this answered your question, would you mind marking this as the accepted answer @AmandeepMidha? 
I also found it as a solution to a similar issue.